# Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token }

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax-error

Yes, that's a chrome's console error that pops up on a click of a button. I think that these errors occur on the basis of the markup but then that's awkward because markup errors should directly come up when the page is loaded but this error comes up on the click of a button.

Here's the **important** HTML for this question:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <script>
        var offers = <? php echo PostOffer::GetOffers($_GET["id"]); ?> ;
        for (var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++) {
            var date = offers[i].Date.split(" ");
            document.write('<div class="row-fluid offer">' +
                '<div class="span2">' +
                '<img class="profile_picture" src="' + offers[i].Picture_Path + '" />' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="span10">' +
                '<div class="row-fluid">' +
                '<div class="username">' +
                '<p style="font-weight: bold;">' + offers[i].Name + '</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="row-fluid">' +
                '<div class="content">' +
                '<p class="content">' + offers[i].Text + '</p>' +
                '<textarea class="hide span12" id="edited_content">' + offers[i].Text + '</textarea>' +
                '<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick="editPostOffer("<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>", ' + offers[i].Offer_ID + ', "aaaaaaaaa")">Save Edits</button>&nbsp;' +
                '<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small cancel_edits">Cancel Edits</button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="row-fluid">' +
                '<div class="date">' +
                '<p class="pull-right"><strong><span class="muted">Offered on: </span></strong>' + date[0] + '</p>' +
                '</div>');
            if (offers[i].Username == "<?php echo $_SESSION["
            username "]; ?>") {
                document.write('<div class="controls pull-right">' +
                    '<a href="" class="no_link edit_offer">Edit</a>&nbsp;' +
                    '<a href="" class="no_link" onclick="showDeleteOfferModal(' + offers[i].Offer_ID + ');">Delete</a> |&nbsp;' +
                    '</div>');
            }
            document.write('</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<hr />');
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$.post("admin/post_offer/edit_post_offer.php", { id: offer_id, text: edited_content }, function (data) {
    if (data.status == "success") {
        console.log("A");
    }
}, 'json');
```

Can you tell me why that's happening?

Comment: I think it breaks here: `"<?php echo $_SESSION["
            username "]; ?>"`

Comment: Your button's `onclick` property has nested `"` which won't work

Comment: Never debug HTML/JavaScript by looking at php code! Look at what is rendered.

Comment: Never mix PHP and JavaScript together.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui `onclick="editPostOffer("<?php echo ...`

Comment: But without PHP I cannot do the work. :/

Comment: Sure you can, have your php output data into an attribute on the element, then have javascript read from said attributes.

Comment: sorry, i'm not going to give a full example of that, there are plenty of existing. search for replacing onclick attributes with event binding.

Comment: Debug it. If it pops up in Chrome's console then it should also let you know what line the exception occurs on. Take a look at your rendered code. See if your PHP is complaining or breaking something. Also, since you're using jQuery, there are much better ways to add HTML - like putting the HTML in a hidden template element, cloning it, replacing a couple of the clone's subelements' contents, then inserting that into the body.

Comment: I strongly second @epascarello's comment. You can't debug client-side problems by looking at the PHP code. You need to look at the actual HTML code *generated* by the PHP, i.e. what the browser actually sees. The browser doesn't even know that you used PHP! All it sees is the resulting HTML/CSS/JavaScript that is downloaded. It doesn't matter that you "need PHP to do the work." You can simply do a View Source in the browser or use the developer tools to see the actual code that the browser receives.